# Trouble making a ggmsa alignment plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm having trouble making an ggmsa alignment plot. I want to do a figure just like this:
[image]

I already have my alignment in .fasta. Here's part of it

> At5g01950 |626-899
> FSSSTLVGRGGYGKVYRGVLSDN-TVAAIKRAD--EGSLQ-GEKEFLNEIELLSRLHHRN
> LVSLIGYCDEESE-QMLVYEFMSNGTLRDWLSAK--GKESLSFGMRIRVALGAAKGILYL
> HTEANPPVFHRDIKASNILLDPNFNAKVADFGLSRLAPVLEDEEDVPKHVSTVVRGTPGY
> LDPEYFLTHKLTDKSDVYSIGVVFLELLTGMHAISHGK---------NIVREVKTAEQRD
> -------MMVSLIDKRME-PW----SMESVEKFAALALRCSHDSPEMRPGMAEVVKELES
> L---------L
> HPCA1 |631-905
> FSEANDVGGGGYGKVYRGILPNG-QLIAIKRAQ--QGSLQ-GGLEFKTEIELLSRVHHKN
> VVRLLGFCFDRNE-QMLVYEYISNGSLKDSLSGK--SGIRLDWTRRLKIALGSGKGLAYL
> HELADPPIIHRDIKSNNILLDENLTAKVADFGLSKLVGDPEK-----THVTTQVKGTMGY
> LDPEYYMTNQLTEKSDVYGFGVVLLELLTGRSPIERGKYVVREVK--TKMNKSRSLYD--
> --------LQELLDTTIIASSG---NLKGFEKYVDLALRCVEEEGVNRPSMGEVVKEIEN
> I---------M
> THE1 |510-783
> FDESSLLGVGGFGRVYKGTLEDG-TKVAVKRGN--PRSEQ-GMAEFRTEIEMLSKLRHRH
> LVSLIGYCDERSE-MILVYEYMANGPLRSHLYGA--DLPPLSWKQRLEICIGAARGLHYL
> HTGASQSIIHRDVKTTNILLDENLVAKVADFGLSKTGPSLDQ-----THVSTAVKGSFGY
> LDPEYFRRQQLTEKSDVYSFGVVLMEVLCCRPALN--PVLPREQV--NIAEWAMAWQKKG
> -------LLDQIMDSNLTGKV----NPASLKKFGETAEKCLAEYGVDRPSMGDVLWNLEY
> A----------

I think I was able to import it to R with

```
fasta_file_path <- "path/to/your/file.fasta"
```

, since fasta_file_path appears in Enviroment.

But now I dont know how to go on. If I follow the steps as specified in this site
http://yulab-smu.top/ggmsa/articles/ggmsa.html

I get this error:

```
Error in if (freq1 > 0.9 && freq2 > 0) { :
```

absent value where TRUE/FALSE is necessary (free translation here)

Please help me solving this problem.

Thank you